# Does a Boost test suite exist?

Tags: c++, boost, porting

I'm working on building the Boost platform for a currently unsupported toolchain. Obviously we'd like to verify that the compiler is building everything OK, so we've some measure of how successful the porting is going. However it's not immediately clear whether or not Boost has such a test suite, good ol' Google fails me (or I fail at Google...) as I can only seem to get results on the Boost Test unit testing library. Does anyone know of such a Boost test suite?

GCC have a little bit of info here (http://gcc.gnu.org/testing/testing-boost.html), but they mention that their regression suite takes around 5 minutes to run on a Pentium 3 - which doesn't suggest to me that it's particularly comprehensive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Boost regression test suite](http://www.boost.org/development/test.html)?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to go to the 'status' directory and run bjam there. If you are using GCC, and your target system does not have problems with threads or unicode, you should not see any failures at all.